# Codeception Bootstrap Error - Given expression is not a regex

Tags: php, laravel-4, codeception

I just pulled in the latest version of Codeception using Composer and ran `vendor/bin/codecept bootstrap` and received the error when it tried to the Build Inital Guy Classes:

`PHP InvalidArgumentException:  Given expression is not a regex.` In: 
`vendor/symfony/finder/Symfony/Component/Finder/Expression/Regex.php on line 77`

It actually does seem to complete, but whenever I run `vendor/bin/codecept run` I also get this same error.

For reference i'm using:

- Laravel Latest
- Composter Latest
- PHP 5.4.25

Thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you can disable xdebug for php5-cli.